# M2 MacBook Air connect external monitor directly (27" Samsung ViewFinity S60UA)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, thunderbolt

Is it possible to connnect the **27" Samsung ViewFinity S60UA** monitor directly to an M2 MacBook Air via USB-C to USB-C cable?

If not, what should I look for in a monitor to connect it directly to the M2 MacBook Air?

I'm asking to see if I should be looking for a monitor to connect directly to the M2 Air or prefer a Thunderbolt hub and connect the monitor through that.

Comment: From what I read at the Samsung site, this device has a USB-C port so you can connect directly with your M2 Air. You shouldn't need a T-bolt hub. Make sure you have a USB-C data cable (not a power connection cable.) [This cable](https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Monitor-Adapter-Delivery/dp/B0BNW5CS1B?th=1) should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple USB-C to USB-C cable (which probably comes with the product).

From the [Technical Specifications](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/27--s60ua-qhd-high-resolution-monitor-with-usb-type-c-ls27a600uunxgo/#specs) page:

> Ditch the clutter and enjoy simplicity. Samsung high resolution monitor features a USB type-C port to power your laptop and transmit data with just one cable. With multiple USB 3.0 ports, you can also plug devices directly into the monitor for a clearer, cleaner workspace.

With the one cable you’ll get:

- Power (charging your Mac)
- Display
- Ethernet
- USB3 ports

Basically, there’s a hub built into a monitor meaning you don't need a third party hub/dock or any special adapter to connect to this monitor.